# Restore old Windows backup after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, backup, windows-10-upgrade, restore

I have a Windows 10 Home machine that was upgraded automatically some time ago from Windows 8.1 and it now turns out that one of the apps, a CAD type application that renders in 3D, had serious performance issues when asked to render a design.

Contacted support and their VERY short reply was,

```
OS: Windows 8.1
App Version: blah
```

I think the Windows 10 roll-back grace period has lapsed but I think have a Windows 8.1 backup that I made from months ago. If I restore that (not sure of exact process at this stage), can I get the 8.1 system back and will it be functional? Will it be able to get security updates etc?

EDIT:

- By functional I meant that it might start complaining that it was non genuine or cause reboots to force you to get valid license something along those lines.
- It was a system backup using Windows 8's own backup tool.

Comment: If it's fully functional depends how you created the backup.  Why don't you just use comparability mode instead?  I am not sure how an application supports Windows 8.1 and not Windows 10.  Of course if it's functional it can receive updates

Comment: @Ramhound me bad, poor choice of words. I'll update the question.

Comment: Just backup your personal files, download the 8.1 ISO, then install 8.1.  You won't be able to restore your 8.1 installion from the backups you have